# How to colour the digits ex:6,7,8 number from database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$number=$row['plate_number'];
```

ex:

```
89786
74867
1687
86767
56786
78611
78686
```

i wanted to colour 786 countinues or 6,7,8 only single digit should red not multiple digits in the case 78686 it should red first 786 remaining 86normal colour

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: actually i have many number in column, i wanted 786 digit should color as red while showing front end...... number:78686 in this  first 786 (in red colour) remaining 86normal colour

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$numbers=$row['plate_number'];

foreach($numbers as $number) { 

for($i = 0; $i < count($number); $i++) { 
    if(...somecondi) { 
        echo '<span style="color: #somecolor">'.$number[$i].'</span>';
    } else {
        .... repeat whatever.
    }
}}
```

Comment: actually i have many number in column, i wanted 786 digit should color as red while showing front end...... number:78686 in this first 786 (in red colour) remaining 86normal colour

Comment: inside foreach do the same

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery plugin its so easy

Replacing the content with  is also an option. There is one more option that you can try which is Jquery plugins. [Here](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) is one of them.

You can use it like this

```
$('body').text().highlight('my text to highlight');
```